# Padding of one flex item influence the rest of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex parent with 2 inputs.One `email` input and one `submit` input.

On the `email` input i set some padding to move the `placeholder` text.This way, the `email` inputs height will grow(what i was expecting), but the problem is that the `submit` inputs height will grow as well.

Why this is happening and how can i stop it? I want the `submit` input to have a height smaller than the `email` input.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer__form">
        <input type="email" class="footer__form--email" placeholder="enter your email for updates">
        <input type="submit" class="footer__form--submit u-uppercase-text" value="sign up">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 &__form {
    flex-basis: 49%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;

     &--email {
      flex: 0 0 65%;
      padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
      }

    &--submit {
      flex: 0 0 30%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am added `align-items:center;`. because, default `align-items:` is `stretch`

```css
.footer__form {
    flex-basis: 49%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items:center;
}
     .footer__form--email {
      flex: 0 0 65%;
      padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
      }

    .footer__form--email--submit {
      flex: 0 0 30%;
      font-weight: 700;

    }
```

```html
<div class="footer__form">
        <input type="email" class="footer__form--email" placeholder="enter your email for updates">
        <input type="submit" class="footer__form--submit u-uppercase-text" value="sign up">
</div>
```